# Alignment between horizontal scrolling and SVG Path chart - React Native

Tags: javascript, animation, react-native

I'm trying to plot my data as a line chart with a *Path* using SVG, I used *d3-scale* to scale the x and y values, to draw the line I use *d3-shape* and to calculate the length of the line I used *svg-path-properties*.

I managed to do that okay, now I want to be able to scroll horizontally a cursor in the green part and get the **x** and **y** values of my chart to display it.

I've created a Animated.View (which does interpolation) that inside has the cursor. I use refs to manage the cursor position and chage the label's value, only the first and last are OK.

But, the value the label shows does not correspond to the chart's values.

Any hint or help would be appreciated!

**Here is a Snack with [my code](https://snack.expo.io/B1gIMXnS4)**

This is my Chart.js code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Dimensions, Animated, TextInput } from 'react-native'
import { Svg, Path} from 'react-native-svg'
import * as path from 'svg-path-properties'
import * as shape from 'd3-shape'
import { scaleTime, scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale'

const d3 = { shape }

const height = 200
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window')
const verticalPadding = 5
const cursorRadius = 10


export default class Chart extends React.Component {

  cursor = React.createRef()
  label = React.createRef()

  state = {
    x: new Animated.Value(0),
    ready: false,
  }

  moveCursor(value) {
    const { x, y } = this.properties.getPointAtLength(this.lineLength - value)

    if (this.label.current) {
      const labelY = this.scaleY.invert(y)
      const labelX = this.scaleX.invert(x)
      this.label.current.setNativeProps({ text: `${Math.round(labelY)}-${labelX}` })
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {

    const { data, yMax, yMin } = this.props
    this.scaleX = scaleTime().domain([data[0].x, data[data.length - 1].x]).range([0, width])
    this.scaleY = scaleLinear().domain([yMin, yMax]).range([height - verticalPadding, verticalPadding])

    this.line = d3.shape.line()
      .x(d => this.scaleX(d.x))
      .y(d => this.scaleY(d.y))
      .curve(d3.shape.curveBasis)(data)

    this.properties = path.svgPathProperties(this.line)

    this.lineLength = this.properties.getTotalLength()

    this.setState({ ready: true }, () => {
      this.state.x.addListener(({ value }) => this.moveCursor(value));
      this.moveCursor(0)
    })

  }

  render() {
    const { line, lineLength } = this
    const { ready, x } = this.state

    if (!ready) {
      return null
    }

    const translateX = x.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, width],
      outputRange: [width - (cursorRadius * 2), 0],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    })


    return (

      <View style={styles.root}>

        <Svg {...{ width, height }}>
          <Path d={line} fill="transparent" stroke="blue" strokeWidth={5} />
        </Svg>

        <View style={styles.scroll}>

          <Animated.View style={[styles.cursor, { transform: [{ translateX }] }]}>
            <View ref={this.cursor} />
          </Animated.View>

          <Animated.ScrollView
            style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
            contentContainerStyle={{ width: lineLength * 2 }}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            scrollEventThrottle={16} //we want our own onScroll to be called every 16ms
            bounces={false}
            // onScroll function
            onScroll={Animated.event([
              {
                nativeEvent: {
                  contentOffset: { x },
                },
              },
            ],
              { useNativeDriver: true },
            )}
            horizontal
          />
        </View>

        <View>
          <TextInput editable={false} selectTextOnFocus={false} ref={this.label} />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
  },
  scroll: {
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  },
  cursor: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: cursorRadius * 2,
    height: cursorRadius * 2,
    borderRadius: cursorRadius,
    borderColor: '#367be2',
    borderWidth: 3,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  }
})
```

[image: my app]

Comment: Looks good after hand charting the points, just the scale of your scroll and the chart are not equal it seems, and alignment seems a bit off.  Add some padding and make sure they line up.  Hope this helps.  I played with it a bit here: https://snack.expo.io/Hksmu52BV

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time! Yes, I have a problem with alignment, I can't seem to figure out how to make them line up. I've tried your snack, but I saw no changes, when the chart is at max (100) it shows another value.